# .htaccess - two conditions – for https and for non-https subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have a ssl certificate for my site.

I’m using htaccess to redirect everyone to the https url of my site.

ie anyone typing in `http://www.example.com` or just `www....` will get redirected to the https address.

That all works fine.

But now I’ve created the subdomain `http://www.blog.example.com`

This is not ssl protected.
So I need this url not to get redirect to the https

This as what i currently have as my htaccess:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; "
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.blog.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Tried quite a few things but doesn’t work. have been searching other questions on here but their solutions dont seem to work. any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; "
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !blog\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: yes it works. thank you!. i took out the last condition as i dont need that. but thanks. so in conclusion; if you stack up the conditions, it works like a IF...AND. IF cond1 AND cond2 AND cond3...do... I was not aware it worked like that. thanks

Comment: @Lan yeah, all the conditions are inherently "AND"ed together, unless you use the `[OR]` flag.